# How is the switch case evaluated?

Tags: c

How is the calculation in the following program done in switch case? Why is the last case evaluated in this code?

I am new to learn C language and I can't get exact defination.

C code:

```
#incluse<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ch ='a'+'b';

    switch(ch)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
        printf("you enterd b\n");
    case 'A':
        printf("a as in ashar\n");
    case 'b'+'a':
        printf("you enterd a and b\n");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to use of `break` in switch case :

```
switch(ch)
{
case 'a':
    // some expressions
    break;
case 'b':
    printf("you enterd b\n");
    break;
case 'A':
    printf("a as in ashar\n");
    break;
case 'b'+'a':
    printf("you enterd a and b\n");
    break;
}
```

The reason is when the variable being switched on is equal to a case, the statements following that case will execute until a `break` statement is reached. Not every case needs to contain a `break`. If no `break` appears, the flow of control will fall through to subsequent cases until a break is reached.

Please visit [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm)

In your program `int ch = 'a' + 'b'` is the same `case 'b'+'a':`, so the `printf("you enterd a and b\n");` expression will be result.

you can ***[Try online](http://cpp.sh/85yab)***

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `switch(ch)` causes control to jump to the `case` label whose expression matches the value of `ch` (if there is one). Since `ch` has the value `'a'+'b'`, and `'a'+'b'` equals `'b'+'a'`, control jumps to the `case 'b'+'a'`.

Incidentally, when one wants each section of code in a `switch` statement to be separate, one must put a `break;` statement at the end of each section (or some other jump statement), as in:

```
switch (ch)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
        printf("You entered a or b.\n");
        break;
    case 'A':
        printf("A as in ashar.\n");
        break;
    case 'b'+'a':
        printf("You entered a and b.\n");
        break;
}
```

Also note that you will not obtain the value `'a'+'b'` when a user enters the characters “a“ and “b”. In C, `'a'+'b'` is the sum of the numerical code for the character `a` and the numerical code for the character `b`. It is not a string concatenation of the two characters.

Answer (score -1):

Switch case works like this, if ch == 'a' then case 1 will get executed else if ch == 'b' case 2 will get executed and so on. After each case break statement is kept to stop the overflow  in between cases.

Comment: I don't think it translates to _"else if"_. Maybe you wanted to say _"another if"_? Like a chain of `if` statements instead of `if ... else if`

Comment: I think it can be translated to if else because we are using break statement in each case. So, it works loke if one condition satisfies other all conditions wont execute.

Comment: True. I was referring to the case where there's no `break` statement. If you do have that, then you're right, it is an `if...else`

Comment: But switch case should have break statement. And that's how it works ! If you say I'm wrong then you are implying that switch case is wrong.

Comment: `switch...case` does not necessarily have `break` statements, the code without them will compile in most languages. __But__ without them the behavior of `switch..case` changes, and it's also considered a good practice to have them

Comment: If switch case doesn't have break statements then how can someone use it or what is the purpose of having such thing.